# Do Unicode's line breaking rules require the last character to be a mandatory break?

Tags: unicode, line-breaks

I'm trying to use libunibreak (https://github.com/adah1972/libunibreak) to mark the possible line breaks in some given unicode text.

Libunibreak gives back four possible options for each code unit in some text:

```
LINEBREAK_MUSTBREAK
LINEBREAK_ALLOWBREAK
LINEBREAK_NOBREAK
LINEBREAK_INSIDEACHAR
```

Hopefully these are self explanatory. I would expect that MUSTBREAK corresponds to newline characters like LF. However, for any given text Libunibreak always indicates that the last character is MUSTBREAK

So for example with the string "abc", the output would be [NOBREAK,NOBREAK,MUSTBREAK]. For "abc\n" the output would be [NOBREAK,NOBREAK,NOBREAK,MUSTBREAK]. I use the MUSTBREAK attribute to start a new line when drawing text so the first case ("abc") creates an extra linebreak that shouldn't be there.

Is this behaviour what Unicode specifies or is this a quirk of the library implementation I'm using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is what the Unicode line breaking algorithm specifies. Rule LB3 in [UAX #14: Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm, section 6.1 "Non-tailorable Line Breaking Rules"](http://unicode.org/reports/tr14/#BreakingRules) says:

> Always break at the end of text.

The spec further explains:

> [This rule is] designed to deal with degenerate cases, so that there is [...] at least one line break for the whole text.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and precise answer!

Comment: so since libunibreak takes a language parameter, does that mean that it doesn't support having multiple languages on a single line of text? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917389