# UAX#14 with libunibreak and a single line of text in multiple languages

Tags: unicode

Consider a single line of text with words in multiple langues. This requires running the line-breaking algorithm on each span of text separately since the line-breaking function takes a language parameter.

But then the algorithm puts a hard break at the end of each piece of text.

Is this a limitation of UAX#14 or libunibreak? And is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> limitation of UAX#14 or libunibreak

Of libunibreak. To verify that's true, just look at a [different implementation](http://p3rl.org/Unicode::LineBreak), that one offers a more fine-grained API than just "language". It's not a work-around, but an alternative; for your C project, you should be able to include the underlying [sombok](https://github.com/hatukanezumi/sombok) instead of libunibreak.

Comment: thanks, didn't know about sombok. I'm still not sure that libunibreak doesn't follow the standard though, since the standard specifies a hard like break at the end of the text.